# minor: layover and stop-over tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

Why do we have the [layovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layovers) (in one word) and [stop-overs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stop-overs) (hyphenated) tags? Maybe it would be nicer to have both in one word or both hyphenated. I don't have the rights to change it myself though.

suggestion:  [layovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layovers) [stopovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stopovers)

EDIT: I don't ask about the difference of meanings, there was [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/in-the-context-of-air-travel-are-layovers-different-to-stopovers) a while ago that states the difference, as @Ankur Banerjee underlined it.

Comment: Just as a reminder, I asked this question so that people with enough reputation could add the synonym [tag:stopovers] to [tag:stop-overs] (and use it as main tag), because I  don't have that much reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has annoyed me too.

I think they're different because different people made them and only moderators can change them.

I just had a quick look with [Google's N-gram tool](http://books.google.com) and it seems the single-word version is the most popular in each case:

- [layovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layovers)
- [stopovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stopovers)

Maybe retain hyphenated versions as synonyms too, that never hurts.

Answer (score 1):

[Because layovers and stopovers mean different things](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7144/108). Not that I'm sure people generally know what the difference is, and thus use it interchangeably. Perhaps we should merge it. I'd say **merge** with [layovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layovers) as main tag.

Comment: sorry I should have mentionned it in the question, I know they're different meanings, the only thing is that layover is in one word and stop-over is in two words separated by a hyphen.