# September 2016 Tag Rename & Synonym MegaQuestion

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since [The previous version of this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3538) is no longer attracting the attention of any moderators despite my efforts, it's time for a new Tag Renaming and Synonymizing topic.

So let's once more compile a list of tags to be renamed or synonymized to make it easier for the mods.

Below is a community wiki answer to be edited by adding the tags to be renamed and the edit status. The mods can then monitor the post for edits and act accordingly.

I have seeded the lists with the ones that were sitting ignored in the old question, plus a new synonym-in-waiting I spotted that led me to take this action.

Answer (score 5):

### Instructions

Mark the tags to be renamed below.

- The html arrow symbol ⇒ denotes renaming operations
- The html arrow symbol ← denotes synonym-creation operations

Once done, mark the renamed tags using the html tick ✔ using the `&#10004;` html code.

---

#### Old name - New Name - Status

- [wrong-example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrong-example) ⇒ [right-example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right-example) - ✔

***To work on***

- [sex](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) ⇒ [sexual-relations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-relations) (IATA use SEX for Sembach Kaserne; this suggested tag-rename has found disagreement, please discuss before renaming)

***Done***

- [uae-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uae-citizens)   ⇒ [emiri-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emiri-citizens) [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations) - ✔
- [winterbash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash)   ⇒ [winter-bash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-bash) (meta) - Sorry, *mea culpa*. - ✔
- [baltics](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baltics)   ⇒ [baltic-region](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baltic-region) [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltic_region) - ✔
- [rvs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rvs) ⇒ [motor-homes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-homes) [See](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/rvs/info) - ✔
- [art](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art)  ⇒ [artworks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artworks) - ✔
- [air-baltic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-baltic)   ⇒ [airbaltic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbaltic) [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirBaltic) - ✔
- [jetlag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jetlag) ⇒ [jet-lag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jet-lag)  - ✔
- [delta-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-airlines)   ⇒ [delta-air-lines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-air-lines) [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Air_Lines) - ✔
- [malaysian-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaysian-airlines)   ⇒ [malaysia-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaysia-airlines) [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines)  - ✔
- [stop-overs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stop-overs) ⇒ [stopovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stopovers) [ref] ([minor: layover and stop-over tags](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/minor-layover-and-stop-over-tags))  - ✔
- [air-asia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-asia) ⇒ [airasia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airasia) - ✔
- [czech-republic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/czech-republic) ⇒ [czechia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/czechia) [See here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2016/04/15/the-czech-republic-is-getting-a-new-name-czechia/?utm_term=.48caf63f89c4), also currently the name on Google Maps - ✔
- [offroad](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offroad) ⇒ [off-road](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-road) - ✔
- [import-tax](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import-tax)   ⇒ [import-taxes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import-taxes)  - ✔
- [submarine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/submarine)   ⇒ [submarines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/submarines) - ✔
- [child-safety-seat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-safety-seat)  ⇒ [child-safety-seats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-safety-seats) - ✔
- [lock-screen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lock-screen)   ⇒ [lock-screens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lock-screens) - ✔
- [short-connection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-connection) ⇒ [short-connections](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-connections) - ✔
- [in-flight-service](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-flight-service) ⇒ [in-flight-services](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-flight-services) - ✔
- [el-salvador-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-salvador-citizens)   ⇒ [salvadoran-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salvadoran-citizens) [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations), [adjectival form](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/country-citizen-tags-convention-needed), [also](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1928/demonyms-again-georgia-citizens-or-georgian-citizens) - ✔
- [roundabout](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roundabout)   ⇒ [roundabouts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roundabouts) - ✔
- [sweden-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweden-citizens)   ⇒ [swedish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swedish-citizens) [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations) - ✔
- [tajik-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajik-citizens)   ⇒ [tajikistani-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajikistani-citizens) [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations) - ✔
- [jr-pass](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jr-pass) ⇒ [jr-passes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jr-passes) - ✔
- [invitation-letter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invitation-letter) ⇒ [invitation-letters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invitation-letters) - ✔
- [visa-duration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-duration) ⇒ [visa-expiration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-expiration) - ✔
- [airport-terminal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-terminal) ⇒ [airport-terminals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-terminals) - ✔
- [marriages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriages) ⇒ [weddings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weddings) (A marriage is the entirety of a a couple's married life together, we don't cover all of that. Our current questions are just about "getting married" ie "weddings') - ✔
- [louvre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/louvre) ⇒ [the-louvre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-louvre) - ✔
- [oyster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oyster) ⇒ [oyster-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oyster-card) - ✔
- [connecting-flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connecting-flight) ⇒ [connecting-flights](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connecting-flights) - ✔
- [bolivian-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bolivian-citizen) ⇒ [bolivian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bolivian-citizens) - ✔
- [flyingblue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flyingblue) ⇒ [flying-blue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying-blue) - ✔
- [china-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-rail) ⇒ [china-railway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-railway) - ✔
- [vayama](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayama) ⇒ [vayama.com](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayama.com) - ✔
- [croatia-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/croatia-citizens) ⇒ [croatian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/croatian-citizens) - ✔
- [zimbabwean-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zimbabwean-citizen) ⇒ [zimbabwean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zimbabwean-citizens) - ✔
- [farsi-language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farsi-language) ⇒ [persian-language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persian-language) [see](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~karimi/Persian%20or%20Farsi.pdf) - ✔
- [eritrean-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eritrean-citizen) ⇒ [eritrean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eritrean-citizens)  - ✔
- [jamaican-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jamaican-citizen) ⇒ [jamaican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jamaican-citizens)  - ✔
- [mozambican-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mozambican-citizen) ⇒ [mozambican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mozambican-citizens) - ✔
- [casino](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casino) ⇒ [casinos](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casinos) - ✔
- [bank-statement](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bank-statement) ⇒ [bank-statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bank-statements) - ✔
- [proof-of-accomodation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-accomodation) ⇒ [proof-of-accommodation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-accommodation) - ✔
- [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) ⇒ [drones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) - ✔
- [standard-visitor-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-visitor-visa) ⇒ [standard-visitor-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-visitor-visas) - ✔
- [ecuador-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador-citizens) ⇒ [ecuadorian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuadorian-citizens) - ✔
- [st-maarten](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/st-maarten) ⇒ [sint-maarten](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sint-maarten) (no questions use those tags, nothing to rename)
- [visa-refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusal) ⇒ [visa-refusals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusals) ✔
- [visa-rejection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-rejection) ⇒ [visa-rejections](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-rejections) ✔
- [goa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goa) ⇒ [goa-india](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goa-india) Three letter tags are reserved for [IATA codes](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126/standardizing-on-airport-tags) [though some are in use for airlines] (IATA use GOA for Genoa Cristoforo Colombo Airport)  ✔
- [leh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leh)⇒ [leh-india](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leh-india) (IATA use LEH for Le Havre Octeville Airport) ✔
- [gsm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsm) ⇒ [gsm-mobile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsm-mobile) (IATA use GSM for Qeshm International Airport) ✔
- [fmm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fmm) ⇒ [fmm-tourist-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fmm-tourist-card) (IATA use FMM for Memmingen Airport) ✔
- [vfs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfs) ⇒ [vfs-global](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfs-global) [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFS_Global) ✔
- [dragonair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonair) ⇒ [cathay-dragon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cathay-dragon) [See](https://www.dragonair.com/ka/en_HK/about-us/about-our-airline/history-and-milestones.html) ✔

#### Synonym Target - Origin - Status

- [example-tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-tag) ← [example-synonym](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-synonym) - ✔

***To work on***

***Done***

- [iraqi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraqi-citizens) ← [iraq-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraq-citizens) [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations)  - ✔
- [maltese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maltese-citizens) ← [malta-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malta-citizens) [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations)   - ✔
- [bounties](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounties) ← [bounty](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty) (note: metaTSE) - ✔
- [borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders) ← [land-borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land-borders) - ✔
- [bookings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookings) ← [airline-booking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-booking) - ✔
- [train-stations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train-stations) ← [railway-station](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railway-station) - ✔
- [exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange) ← [currency-exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange) - ✔
- [events](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events) ← [events-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events-travel) [see] ([Do we need both tags "event travel" and "events"?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/do-we-need-both-tags-event-travel-and-events)) - ✔
- [health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) ← [medication](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medication) (medicine is already a synonym of [health]) - ✔
- [sport-equipment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport-equipment) ← [sports-equipment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports-equipment) - ✔
- [phi-phi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phi-phi) ← [ko-phi-phi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ko-phi-phi) (re consistency with Wikipedia) - ✔
- [events](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events) ← [event-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-travel) (This is **Travel** SE) [see](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/do-we-need-both-tags-event-travel-and-events) - ✔
- [new-south-wales](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-south-wales) ← [nsw](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nsw) - ✔
- [airport-transfer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-transfer) ← [transfer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) (based on current usage) - ✔
- [standard-visitor-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-visitor-visas) ← [standard-visitor-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-visitor-visa) - ✔

Comment: I did the merging and renaming, expect for the last one. I also think that this should be discussed.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: Oh frabjous day! I think the outcome back in the day wrt other countries visa waivers was that we created a [tag:visa-free-travel]. I'm not sure what the optimal solution is.

Comment: @pnuts: oh the thing about VWP is not whether it should be singular or plural but whether in actuality it is only in fact used for the US program by that name. If people also use it to refer to other countries that waive the need for a visa to certain people then it wouldn't make a good synonym.

Comment: Another option is to make [tag:vwp] a synonym of [tag:visa-free-travel] which covers the visa waivers of other countries, the visa waivers of the US, and other ways of visiting a country whether or not they do or should include the term "waiver". But I'm not sure if that's best either. I am sure that having all three tags is not best.

Comment: @pnuts: Because it's the name of a system. It's for questions about the whole system, not just about the actual card bit you can hold in your hand.

Comment: @pnuts: Thanks! I used to be a good speller before I got old \-:

Comment: There is not a named system or organization "Visa" or "visas" other than the payment card.

Comment: @pnuts: [It seems you have not read this meta thread. Let me know if anything in it remains unclear.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/336/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats)

Comment: Oyster cards is not terrible but oyster card seems better to me as it literally covers the system by that name rather than just the cards and 'oyster' alone just looks too much like seafood for those of us who don't use the system.

Comment: @pnuts: Of course but it's only clear to people familiar to that city, for everyone else oyster has no context and seems just like clam or mussel or scallop or squid or octopus which for all I know might be brand names for some travel pass system in some small city that I also don't have context for. Clarity is better when confusion may arise.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever mentioned the JR Pass system. That would work better singular for me too, but in any case it's a minor point. As long as we don't just have "oyster" or "octopus" or other generic words that happen also to be used as brands and which people could misinterpret due to not knowing the context when they're tagging questions about seafood or whatever. If you're confused about Japanese train travel tags you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in. I sorted the suggested synonyms so that we easily see which ones are done.

Comment: Some tags merged, more to follow later tonight. Check out the one tag that we couldn't merge.