# Should "esta" and "us-visa-waiver-program" be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should we merge the [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta) and [us-visa-waiver-program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-visa-waiver-program) tags? While there is a technical sense in which they are not exactly the same thing, many questions about "traveling to the US on an ESTA" are questions about the Visa Waiver Program. It doesn't seem reasonable to me that we'd expect questioners to understand the difference.

See [this previous question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/clarify-merge-us-visa-waiver-program-tags) for a related merge, and some comments there suggest merging `esta` as well, but with no resolution to that question.

Comment: I think the distinction is useful. To prevent misuses of the [tag:esta] tag for the other tag, I suggest renaming it to [tag:esta-application].

Comment: I don't think the situation has evolved since 2016.