# Is there a better way to handle tag renames and synonyms, without radical change?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The renaming and synonymising of tags is not working. Some tags are 'broken' (but the issue is perhaps being followed up). However Travel has a better system than I have seen on other SE sites but it could perhaps be improved. Rather than an assortment of sporadic posts such as the most recent of which I am aware [September 2016 Tag Rename & Synonym MegaQuestion](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/september-2016-tag-rename-synonym-megaquestion) I suggest:

1. An annual post, with Title starting with the year
   *IMO the rate of renaming and synonymising required should be much lower in future than in the past, even allowing for a better system increasing usage of such a system.*
2. 'Answers' should be where the specifics are given
   *ie current and proposed – so that when effected just a tick is required, line by line.*
3. All `Answers` should be wikied
   *To encourage the addition of new proposals into an existing answer rather than create a multitude of 'Answers'.*
4. Renames and synonyms should be kept separate
   *A different `A` for each class.*
5. Once all entries in any `A` have been ticked the entire `A` should be 'Accepted' and no further entries added to that `A`
   *Instead start a new `A`. If more than one `A` 'Acceptance' can't be with a green tick, so would need a note to mark the `A` as Closed*.

This however is a hack that somewhat abuses the meta Q&A format. It attempts to work around SE tagging deficiencies in general but which may be worse for a site where we only have a ratio of around 18 users per tag on average (cf SO ~88).

What say you?

Comment: There must be a better way. Let me mull this over.

Comment: No that SE system is just plain horrible. One must have enough rep on the tag on questions jump through a hoop set ablaze with napalm whilst performing a kick flip on a wakeboard playing pokemon blue on a game boy, in order **to suggest** a synonym. Requirements for voting on a synonym are the same with the added requirement of sacrificing a StackExchange intern on a night of red moon during the warmest month of the Australian aboriginal lunar calendar. That's why I concocted the Tag and Synonym MegaQuestion: call a mod, let them do it. Quick and easy.

Comment: What if we have an annual post as you mentioned and then create 3 community wiki answers there. One answer, the accepted one that contains all tags that have been renamed. Another answer that contains all tags that still have to be merged and a third answer were we can put tag merges that have to be discussed? (Maybe a fourth answer with tags than can't be merged for whatever reasons)

Comment: I'm still thinking about the best way to do it. I now realize that the problem with multiple answer is, that we have to copy lines between answers. That's why more cumbersome than just copying lines within the same answer. Maybe as you said, for each batch of renames a separate answer and ticking those off that are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO too complicated. Let's leave the current system as-is, possibly adding a new "tag rename/synonym" post more often.

I have processed all the current tag requests and I'm sure that with 5 mods we could get any (proper) request done within a week at most.